# how to plot a mixed graph in R?

Tags: r, graph-theory

How can I plot a mixed graph in R?

I have used this but doesn't work (in bnlearn he calls 'arc' to a directed edge and 'edge' to an undirected edge):

```
library(bnlearn)
dag=empty.graph(nodes = c("E", "F"))
graphviz.plot(dag)
dag = set.edge(dag, from = "E", to = "F")
dag = set.arc(dag, to = "E", from = "F")
graphviz.plot(dag)
```

As specified in the documentation https://www.bnlearn.com/documentation/man/arcops.html it will overwrite the arc...
(Note that in bnlearn library he calls 'arc' to a directed edge and 'edge' to an undirected edge)

I want to be able to plot a mixed graph like:

[image]

(arc (directed edge) between E and F, also edge (undirected edge) **at the same time**).

(If R cannot do it, is there any other easy tool I could use?, my goal is just to plot)

edit: I just realized thatBayesian Networks need to be acyclic by definition, so I guess I am hopeless with the bnlearn library...

Comment: bnlearn & Rgraphviz can plot a mix of directed / undirected edges but with bnlearn you wont be able to get multiple edges (either directed or not) between two nodes.

Comment: yep, exactly, I was looking to get multiple edges... I guess there is no workaround in R...

Comment: Have a look at the `graph` package - it seems a reaonable thing to expect to be able to do.

Comment: ... yup check out the multi-graphs section in the `graphBAM and MultiGraph classes` vignette at https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/graph.html

Comment: did you find a solution to this? btw is it just for a graphs with few nodes like in your example. If so, it may be easier to do this in raw `graphviz` (as opposed to Rgraphviz) or even latex.